# How to force restart NodeJS process in Heroku in case of unrecoverable error?

Tags: node.js, heroku, crash

One of the 3rd party libraries rarely behaves oddly and gets application into some weird state that's not possible to recover from. So I made an escape hatch to catch the error and then I call `process.exit(0)` in hopes the Heroku would restart it.

Today was the first occurrence of this and unfortunately, it took Heroku about 10 minutes before it decided to restart the dyno. It kept spamming with `error code=H10 desc="App crashed"` along the way.

What could a better way to handle this so Heroku restarts immediately? I would like to avoid calling Heroku API, that's odd workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I think your "escape hatch" is not a good practice to handle a "weird state" of your node application. You should tackle the problem heads-on, maybe remove that 3rd party library and make sure that your application works as expected, all the time.

That being said, the fact that "it took Heroku about 10 minutes" is because you are probably using their 'Common Runtime'. If you want your services to reboot immediately on failure, you will have to look at running them in their 'Private Spaces Runtime'.

From [the docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#dyno-crash-restart-policy):

> The Common Runtime implements an incremental backoff policy for
> crashing dynos
>
> The Private Spaces Runtime does not have a backoff policy. When a dyno
> crashes it will be continuously restarted with no cool-off period.

Comment: Yea, I know it's not ideal, but ripping away 3rd party library and finding an alternative (with its own set of issues) would be way too costly to be worth it. The problem occurs very rarely (like once in 3+ months).

Comment: Did not realize that this delay or backoff policy is actually a feature. That makes total sense. I will have a look at Private Spaces Runtime. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Heroku api, this way you won't get this "App crashed" error:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#dyno-restart

Don't forget to use `Authorization` header:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#authentication